# Removal of ecryptfs

Tags: ecryptfs

Install of Linux Mint recommends drive encryption and uses ecryptfs. Unfortunately, they don't want you of the trouble you are getting into. eCryptfs seems near impossible to remove cleanly. There are "explanations" that are totally unclear on essential steps. The evidence of this is that there continue to be questions on how to remove it.

You can see just what a mess it is by checking out this forum post on Linux Mint Forums, http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=142219&p=754007#p754007.